# Question about a proof of the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~emsilvia/math127/chapter8.pdf

In the last part of the proof of Theorem 8.2.3, why does the inequality $$|f_{M^\ast+1}(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon/2$$ hold uniformly for all $z$? A few lines above it was noted that this inequality holds for a fixed $z$, but this line is supposed to prove uniform convergence.

The author notices that it follows from the fact that $n, z$ were arbitrary, but I don't see how this helps. Yes, the above inequality holds for arbitrary $z$, but $M^\ast$ depends on $z$.

Comment: You pick an arbitrary M, then for each z, we can find an associated M*(z) when the functions are going to get close. Also, there is the remark right below the proof if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

$M^*$ is allowed to depend on $z$, but note that the final result doesn’t depend on $M^*$ (perhaps better notation would be $M^*(z)$), so we can let $M^*$ vary with $z$.